# Find $r$ where $\dfrac{(7n)!}{7^n n!} \equiv r \pmod{7}$, $r \in [[0, 6]]$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I conjecture that:

$\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{(7n)!}{7^n n!} \equiv
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& 1 \text{ if } n \text{ is even} \\
& 6 \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\pmod{7}
\end{equation*}$

Based on hand observations.

- I tried to reduce the factorials as binomial coefficients, that didn't yield to some problem reduction.
- Observing it in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ didn't give much help also.
- Simplifying the $n!$ using the $(7n)!$ didn't help also.
- We can see using p-adic valuations that this expression is never a multiple of 7, due to the fact that all powers of 7 vanish (using Legendre formula for instance).
- Attempts to separating odd / even cases didn't help also.
- Considering the equation $\pmod{7^{n + 1}}$ didn't help also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{(7n)!}{7^n\cdot n!}\equiv \frac{(6!)^n\cdot (7\times 14\times\cdots \times 7n)}{7^n\cdot n!}\equiv\frac{7^n\cdot n!\cdot (6!)^n}{7^n\cdot n!}\equiv (6!)^n\pmod 7$$

Now, use [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

---

This can further be generalized for all primes $p$. We have,

$$\frac{(pn)!}{p^n\cdot n!}\equiv (-1)^n\pmod p$$

Comment: But I don't understand how $(7 × 14 × … × 7n) = 7^n × n!$

Comment: @Raito, $$7\times 14\times\cdots\times 7n=(7\times 1)\times (7\times 2)\times\cdots (7\times n)=7^n\times (1\times 2\times\cdots\times n)=7^n\times n!$$

Answer (score 1):

Induction. $$\frac{(7(n+1))!}{7^{n+1}(n+1)!}\equiv\frac{(7n)!(7n+1)\cdots(7n+6)(7n+7)}{7^nn!7(n+1)}\equiv\frac{(7n)!}{7^nn!}(1\cdot2\cdots6)\equiv-\frac{(7n)!}{7^nn!} \mod 7.$$